# Hot configure Haproxy 1.5

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, haproxy

I had been using this command to restart haproxy with success:

```
sudo haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -sf $(cat /var/run/haproxy.pid)
```

However, after upgrading to recent dev versions of Haproxy 1.5, I noticed that this did not work as expected. More specifically, I ended up with two Haproxy processes running (one old, and the other new).

Is anything changed?

Comment: Can you confirm that the haproxy.pid file only has one entry in it?

Comment: @slm, there is only one entry in the pid file.

Comment: @slm, just upgraded to dev17, and it seems the problem has gone away. was having the problem with earlier dev versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior, but only noticeable if you have long-running connections. The old process will continue to run until all of the connections it's handling are done.

For example, on the haproxy instance for our web server, the old process disappears within seconds. But the haproxy instance in front of our Exchange servers can have the old process around for days because of Outlook and Active Sync connections.

So in your instance, I think it was just luck that you had a long connection open preventing the old process from exiting yet.